# grub> : not able to find files?

Tags: grub-legacy

I have installed grub legacy on my system Ubuntu 13.04 for testing  & learning.
In the shell terminal I typed `grub` & the grub terminal showed up. Then I searched stage1 file as below but got error. What's the issue?

```
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1

Error 15: File not found

grub>
```

I'm following [this link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html&ei=C7fSUp2XDsO-rgeJlIHgCA&usg=AFQjCNEaj0KTivX879nXG0lbQMbHS3aHYg&sig2=ZcF0jYvMVnBN2-GTlX_cbA&bvm=bv.59026428,d.bmk) for study.

Comment: It depends on your partition table. If you have a separate boot partition then you should use `find /grub/stage1`.

Comment: @UVV Thank you. That was the only problem as you told. You can post it as answer so that I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your partition table. If you have a separate boot partition then you should use `find /grub/stage1`